# Packet capture via cmd

Tags: windows, networking

I want to know if there is a tool that I can use to script out packet captures (command line) without having to install anything  (and preferably not even pcap). This is for Windows machines; the tool would be run with administrative credentials.

I just want to glean the source/destination IP and port pair for packets sent in and out. Netstat will not work, because sessions can open and close within milliseconds and would be missed.

Quick googling reveals either I am going to have to pay for an expensive tool or stick to GUI based tools.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Windows 7 and above have this feature built in.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/canberrapfe/archive/2012/03/31/capture-a-network-trace-without-installing-anything-works-for-shutdown-and-restart-too.aspx

> The short version:
>
> 1. Open an elevated command prompt and run: `netsh trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=c:\temp\nettrace-boot.etl` (make sure you have a \temp directory or choose another location).
> 2. Reproduce the issue or do a reboot if you are tracing a slow boot scenario.
> 3. Open an elevated command prompt and run: `netsh trace stop`
>
> Your trace will be stored in c:\temp\nettrace-boot.etl** or where ever you saved it. You can view the trace on another machine using netmon.

Comment: Great, definitely a nice tool for a network administrator

Comment: Do you by any chance know if the resulting file can be analyzed using Wireshark on an Ubuntu 14.04 system?

Comment: Not directly. http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2013/08/16/so-you-want-to-use-wireshark-to-read-the-netsh-trace-output-etl.aspx

Comment: And here I was hoping I could point some less technical Windows users at your fairly simple instructions for capturing a packet trace. Not going to work so well, if I have to guide those same users through all the steps to install another program just for converting the resulting file to a usable format :-/

Comment: At some point, you'll need a technically knowledgeable person to read the trace; whoever that person is can do the conversion.

Comment: @mfinni That technical person would be me, but I don't have any Windows machine to install that tool on.

Comment: Well hey. If you're professionally supporting Windows, it's a reasonable assumption that you have some access to a Windows machine. With VMware Player and an eval copy of Windows, you don't even have to spend any money.

Comment: If you don't like ETL you can always install Network Monitor so you get NMCap, that can capture to cap files from command line :)

Comment: the original request was how to capture traffic without installing software.

Comment: Also, I did find a version of tcpdump that comes prepackaged with pcap. So it allows cmd usage of tcpdump without the need to install pcap.

Comment: @kasperd [link](https://www.microolap.com/products/network/tcpdump/download/)

Comment: @mfinni I am not supporting Windows. I am supporting a webapp hosted on a Debian server. Sometimes customers decide to access this webapp from Windows client machines, and occasionally they report problems which appear to be related to networking problems. It would be nice in such scenarios, if I could point those customers at an easy way to perform a packet capture without needing to install additional software on their machine.

Comment: Right - they can do that with the method I provided. For you to be able to read it, you'll need a Windows machine.

Comment: The current/ working link to @mfinni comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140531052949/http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2013/08/16/so-you-want-to-use-wireshark-to-read-the-netsh-trace-output-etl.aspx I couldn't find it in the Technet Archive