# How can NETSH be used to sniff and collate network traffic?

Tags: windows, networking, network-monitoring, packet-capture

I am trying to capture all network traffic and view it in a human-readable way.

To begin packet capture with netsh, I am running the following command.

`netsh trace start scenario=NetConnection capture=yes report=yes persistent=no maxsize=1024 correlation=yes traceFile=net-trace.etl`

I then use QuickPHP to host a form that takes a username and password and posts it to itself. The trace is then stopped with `netsh trace stop`.

To inspect the captured traffic, the following command is run.

`netsh trace convert input=net-trace.etl output=net-trace-dump.txt dump=txt`

When I read the dumped traffic, the entries are unintelligible and I cannot see the traffic to the QuickPHP server on 127.0.0.1. Additionally, when I import the `.etl` file into Microsoft Network Monitor, the traffic is clumped into a single clump and the QuickPHP traffic still cannot be found.

I have been able to run a capture with Microsoft Network Monitor and see the QuickPHP traffic.

[image]

How can NETSH be used to capture the network traffic and viewed, either in a dumped text file or Microsoft Network Monitor, in a similar way to a capture from Microsoft Network Monitor?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Use wireshark ?

Comment: Use anything other than netsh?

Comment: Wireshark/WinPcap work fine, but the goal is to use just netsh

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/669580/packet-capture-via-cmd/669592#669592

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Packet capture via cmd](https://serverfault.com/questions/669580/packet-capture-via-cmd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `netsh trace start capture=yes` without any of the other stuff. This gets you just a basic packet capture that you can view in Network Monitor.

You don't need to use the ETW providers like `NetConnection` unless you're troubleshooting a Windows Filtering Platform problem or something.

You don't need the `convert` command at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ryan! That's good to know about the ETW providers, however the collected trace is still a unordered mess and I can't find traffic to the QuickPHP server.

Comment: I've found the traffic, stripping back the command worked. Thanks again!